# Jquery each loop with anomynous function not working

Tags: jquery, arrow-functions

i have the following html:

```
  <body>
    <div >
      <h1>OnlineList</h1>
      <ul id="onlineList">
        <li con="123" age="10">Test A</li>
        <li con="234" age="11">Test B</li>
        <li con="345" age="10">Test C</li>
        <li con="456" age="12">Test D</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
```

and i am using jquery as following:

```
var meow = [];
var meow2 = [];

var a = $("li").each(function () 
    {
      meow.push( $(this).attr("age"));
  });

var b = $("li").each( () =>
    
      meow2.push( $(this).attr("age"))
  );

console.log(meow);
console.log(meow2);
```

meow will give me the expected output:

```
["10", "11", "10", "12"]
```

meow2 will give me:

```
[undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]
```

I'm little bit suprised what happend cause i just use an anonymous/arrow function?

Comment: FYI, you are using an anonymous function in both cases. An anonymous function is just a function without a name. It is not synonymous with arrow functions.

Comment: @HereticMonkey sry, you are right!

Comment: Aside from the arrow function scope issue, you should be careful using non-standard attributes in your HTML as it can cause JS/CSS problems. In this case I'd suggest using data attributes instead. Also, you can simplify your code by using `map()`: `let meow = $('li').map((i, el) => $(el).data('age')).get();`. A

Answer (score 0):

If you use the JS ES6 syntax to declare a function "this" is no longer the calling element. You have to use:

```
var b = $("li").each( (index, element) =>

  meow2.push( $(element.currentTarget).attr("age"))
);
```

Comment: i tried it with jsfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/cem6aygz/52/) but its still not working

Comment: Are you sure `element` is the first argument to the function passed to `each`? [The documentation seems to differ](https://api.jquery.com/each/#each-function)...

Comment: Thanks index is the first argument. Thank you!

Comment: @Heretic Monkey Thanks forgot that on each the first parameter is the index. I have edited the answer